# Using Custom Meeting Sharepoint site template in Outlook 

Tags: outlook, site-template

We have developped internally a custom meeting workspace template. This template is available when creating a meeting workspace in SharePoint under the tab "Custom".

I would like my users to be able to schedule their meetings, invite their attendees and such from their Outlook environment. To do so, training will be given to show them how to link the SharePoint Calendar list into their Outlook. Problem is, when creating a "New Meeting Request", and going in the "Meeting Workspace" tab, our custom Workspace template does not appear in the list of available templates.

Is it possible to have it appear in the list of available templates, and if so, do I have to modify something?

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I am also facing this issue. It would be helpful if you can share.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is modifying the out of the box site definitions / webtemp.xml to include your own site definition in the MPS - Section.
The MPS is hardwired in almost everything related to meeting workspaces, so you don't really have any alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by adding the `Template` ID (in my site definition it is `webtemp_CustomMeetingSite.xml`) same as ID of MPS in `WEBTEMP.XML`.

ID of MPS is 2 in `WEBTEMP.XML`. So, my `Template` tag looked like this:

```
<Template Name="CustomMeetingSite" ID="2">
  <Configuration ID="101" 
  ....
  ....
  >    
  </Configuration>
</Template>
```

Hope this helps!