# best customized/branded meeting workspace

Tags: 2007, branding, custom-masterpage, meeting-workspace

I am trying to find customized Meeting Workspace, but google didn't helped me at all, if someone knows please link me,

Default Meeting workspace can be viewed by going to link given below,

[Basic Meeting WorkSpace](http://digsharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/sharepoint-meeting-workspace-sites-how.html)

As I have Been asked what can I do to Improve it, but I dont see any major thing I can add, any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Customizing Meeting Workspaces is not as straight forward as one could expect unfortunately (both SP2007 and SP2010).

First of all you cannot use Web Templates or Custom Site Definitions because Outlook often will be the one creating the sites using web services, and it is only aware of the OOB site definitions.

As i stated in comments elsewhere, feature stapling isnt reliable for meeting templates. I experienced race conditions between modules and list instances when using feature stapling for meeting templates.

I ended up using a custom provisioning provider for my customization task. Something along the lines of this:

```
    class MeetingWorkspaceProvisioningProvider : SPWebProvisioningProvider
    {
        public override void Provision(SPWebProvisioningProperties properties)
        {
            SPWeb site = properties.Web; // NOTE: dont dispose this web!


            // provision Blank Meeting Template
            site.ApplyWebTemplate("MPS#1");

            // your logic here
            // could be creating libraries, pages, adding web parts etc
            // it is a good idea to load an XML file using properties.Data to make provider more generic
        }
    }
```

You will also need a WEBTEMP*.xml file along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Templates xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint">
  <Template Name="MYmeetingWorkspace" ID="10004">
    <Configuration ID="0"
    Title="My Meeting Forum"
    Hidden="FALSE"
    Description="My Meeting Workspace"
    ProvisionAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
    ProvisionClass="MY.MeetingFora.Portal.ProvisioningProviders.MeetingWorkspaceProvisioningProvider"
    ProvisionData="1033\xml\MY\ProvisioningData.xml"
    SubWebOnly="TRUE"
    DisplayCategory="Custom" >
    </Configuration>
  </Template>
</Templates>
```

Comment: With this you won't be able to select the template from outlook which is important for user experience. It's always better to define WebTemplates than Template for meeting workspaces ;)

Comment: Its been a while since i did this customization, but one of the key aspecets whats that it should work with Outlook, so I am quite sure i managed to get it to show in Outlook, but right now I cant remember how. Will dig some more in TFS... :-)

Comment: It works with web template because you can define the Base Template to be meeting workspace. You need to do the same as SharePoint does when you save meeting workspace as template. With a template like this you cannot say what the parent is. You can then also specify what master page to use. Changed this just a couple of days ago. ;)

Comment: AFAIR saving meeting templates is not supported (you will also notice that the "save as template" is removed when on a meeting site). This is because of all the special wiring with Meeting class and GlobalMtgDataList that handles if lists items should filter on meetings or not. You may be right that feature stapling is a good option if you only want to customize master page, but as soon as you start to drop in modules you will experience errors so be warned!

Comment: AFAIR the only pages that are not supported to be saved as template are publishing site. For meeting workspace save site as template was never removed not in SharePoint 2007 and not in SharePoint 2010. On thing that is not supported by meeting workspace is to create subsite beneath a meeting workspace. :)

Comment: Hmm there are definately more than just Publishing sites, but I forget which :-) Meetings has alot of weird wiring behind the scenes. One of the more ugly is the footprint on all SPLists: [bool]MultipleDataList that is used to managed that meeting items are only shown for a specific meeting, and not "globally".

Comment: Thats not wierd if you use the right namespace, classes and caml queries.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4097/discussion-between-anders-rask-and-stefan-bauer)

Comment: I could get the custom meeting template in Outlook by having the `Template` ID same as `Template` ID of MPS in `WEBTEMP.xml` file, which is "2". Check [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10711/using-custom-meeting-sharepoint-site-template-in-outlook/50186#50186) post

Comment: overwriting/reusing existing Microsoft "owned" templates is not supported and could be overwritten in any patch

Answer (score 1):

The meeting workspace use a different master page this Master Page is named mwsdefaulv4.master. You can create your own master page based on this. To deploy and use you use feature stapling to enhance the meeting workspace template.

For more information take a look at http://blog.brianfarnhill.com/2008/03/feature-stapling-why-you-should-love-it

Comment: In my experience feature stapling does *not* work with Meeting workspaces (race conditions). For more details see my comment here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/create-new-site-in-sub-folder#comment-6463

Comment: In the last couple of weeks i played much around with meeting workspace. Created a custom template that uses feature stapling and also found a way how to let meetingwork space appear in Outlook. There are some tricks that can be used.

Comment: It definately depends on what customizations are done. I got it working up to a point: as soon as i started adding files to modules (classic race condition problem when you use feature stapling) it broke. Worth knowing if you wanna go down that road ;-)

Comment: Thats for sure. I learned a lot about SharePoint Meeting Workspace in combination with Outlook and it also depends how to customize meeting workspace or create new templates. I also found some inconsistencies how SharePoint handle things or how Site/Web Templates or Site Definitions will be created. ;) Will do a series of blog posts in the future but first in need to fix up my bad design ;)